# How to pass a new dictionary to a method with a dictionary parameter?

Tags: c#

my call -- I want to pass it a dictionary full of keys and values

```
QueryBuilder query = new QueryBuilder(new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source = D:/chinook.db")); 
Dictionary<string, string> loadDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();


Console.WriteLine(query.Create("albums", loadDictionary)); //What do I replace loadDictionary with?
```

method name

```
    public void Create(string tableName, Dictionary<string, string> columnsAndVals)
    {

        var commandText = $"insert into {tableName}(";

        foreach (var item in columnsAndVals.Keys) // adds keys into command text
        {
            commandText += item + ",";
        }

        commandText += ") values("; 

        foreach (var item in columnsAndVals) // adds values into command text
        {
            commandText += $"@{item},";
        }
            var cmd = new SqliteCommand(commandText, Connection);

        using (cmd)
        {
            foreach (var item in columnsAndVals)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add($"@{columnsAndVals.Keys}, @{columnsAndVals}");
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

I am constructing a method that will use a sql connection to insert a column and a value into a sql database.

To do this, I am using a dictionary to hold the columns and values I want to insert. (e.g. insert into (tableName)(columnsAndVals.Keys) values (columnsAndVals.Values) etc etc)

What I don't understand is how to establish a dictionary in my driver, then pass it as a parameter into my Create method. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You have created the `Dictionary<string, string>` object, now you can add values to it and then pass it to the `Create()` method, which you already did.

Comment: I have tried several different ways to pass it, I was actually using loadDictionary as a placeholder.. but now it gives me an error of "cannont convert from void to bool"

Comment: hi buildbuild, welcome.. in c# you can always pass a dictionary as a parameter, no problem.. but as I understand from your text, you would actually like to convert a Dictionary<string, string> into an SQLite table ? Is that correct ? Can you put your QueryBuilder class in the opening question, so we know what you tried sofar ? If you have the INSERT queries you need, you can open the connection to your SQLite file, pass each INSERT statement to the database using command = new SQLiteCommand(cSql, con); command.ExecuteNonQuery();. The QueryBuilder should prepare the INSERT statements.

Comment: can you share what have you tried in `Create` method?

Comment: @buildbuild `query.Create()` does not return a value (return type is `void`), so you can't use it in `WriteLine()`.

Comment: additionally I want to be able to define values, so whenever I call the method, I want to insert a key and a value... in this iteration it doesn't allow for that (unless I should be establishing those values outside of the method call?

Comment: @Goodies that's exactly what I'm doing, I edited my post but I am unable to test it without fixing my method call..

Comment: @Progman I see! It's always the simple issues, thank you.. I might reedit it to return a string saying if it works or not.

Comment: @buildbuild another remark.. Progman is right so you can proceed.. when you are going to test this, make sure that your Dictionary<string,string> contains some entries. In the above code, your dictionary is empty. Put e.g. loadDictionary ["foor"] = "bar"; and then see if the SQL is welformed. Also, take into account when you want to use this for serious purposes, that passing SQL directly from inputs is unsafe. A user could misuse edit box for Value, result a messed up SQL string. You could avoid that using Entity Framework 6.3 for Sqlite, or.. checking the values before put them in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an `insert` query, in addition to the table name, you need to have **three** lists of values: column name, parameter name, and parameter value. While `Dictionary<TKey, TValue` allows you to pass only **two** lists (keys and values).

Therefore, you need to change the method signature. I would completely reject the `Dictionary`.

You can either pass three separate lists:

```
public int Create(string tableName, List<string> columnNames, List<string> parameterNames, List<object> parameterValues)
```

either a single list with a specially created class:

```
class QueryValue
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public object ParameterValue { get; set; }
}

public int Create(string tableName, List<QueryValue> values)
{
    var columnNames = string.Join(",", values.Select(v => v.ColumnName));
    var parameterNames = string.Join(",", values.Select(v => v.ParameterName));

    var sb = new StringBuilder()
        .Append("insert into ")
        .Append(tableName)
        .Append('(')
        .Append(columnNames)
        .Append(") values(")
        .Append(parameterNames)
        .Append(')');

    var commandText = sb.ToString();
    //Console.WriteLine(commandText); // to see result

    using (var cmd = new SqliteCommand(commandText, Connection))
    {
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(value.ParameterName, value.ParameterValue);
        }
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Call the method like this:

```
var values = new List<QueryValue>
{
    new QueryValue{ ColumnName="a", ParameterName="@a", ParameterValue="aa" },
    new QueryValue{ ColumnName="b", ParameterName="@b", ParameterValue="bb" },
    new QueryValue{ ColumnName="c", ParameterName="@c", ParameterValue="cc" }
};
int rowsAffected = Create("albums", values);
```

Note that the `ExecuteNonQuery` method returns the number of rows affected. Therefore, our `Create` method returns `int`.

You can also use a tuple instead of a separate class.

---

However, I strongly oppose such methods. Their use looks rather crooked and fraught with errors.

Each table must have its own insertion method defined, as well as selections, updates, and deletions.

For example

```
public int InsertUser(int id, string name)
{
    var commandText = "insert into User (id, name) values (@id, @name)";

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, Connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("id", id);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("name", name);

        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Of course, there will be many such methods, but their use is much easier and less error prone.